# Передача переменной через redirect_to и request.user в urlpatterns

Tags: python, django, redirect

Суть проблемы: делаю редирект в urlpatterns функцией redirect_to на определённый адрес, нужно попутно передать русскую строку текста(хотя можно и просто булево значение name=1 например).
Сейчас реализовал как гет-параметр в урл, вот:

```
(r'^foo/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/bar?check=1'}),
```

Но что-то мне кажется, что можно и как-то изящнее, без использования гет-параметров, просто указав переменную=значение.
Есть соображения? Или мой способ - единственный?

Ах да, ещё было бы неплохо влезть в запрос request, что бы использовать его данные в составлении url(конкретно - нужны сведения о текущем пользователе, т.е. request.user). Есть какая-то возможность определить пользователя в urlpatterns? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Юзай urlencode.

```
import urllib

# Это твои GET-параметры, которые ты как-то сюда передал
param1 = 'value1'  
param2 = 'value2'

# Твой какой-то код, паттерны  
params = urllib.urlencode({'param1': param1, 'param2': param2})
(r'^foo/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/bar?%s' % params}),
```

Comment: В принципе хороший способ на русские строки, но это не совсем критично. В идеале - что бы параметры вообще не мелькали, а передавались в фоне. Но спасибо за ответ! Возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 0):

Не мучайтесь с редиректом, явное лучше неявного. Передавайте управление во views.py

```
(r'^foo/$', 'my_view')
```

А там уже и request, и request.GET.get('check'), и request.user.

Comment: Нет, нужен именно редирект, т.к. происходит возврат на страницу, которая висит на строго определённом адресе. А отклик одной страницы на два разных адреса для меня не допустим...

Comment: А что мешает из view сделать HttpResponseRedirect ?

Comment: Вьюха из джанговской библиотеки, а править либы - не есть хорошо.